# What is a Lagrangian submanifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I see references to Lagrangian Submanifolds in the literature but don't know what they are. Is there a relation to Lagrangian Tori (which I also don't know what are). Could someone give a definition that includes an intuitive explanation for what their use is?

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question whether you found these definitions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold#Lagrangian_and_other_submanifolds and http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/LagrangianSubmanifold.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a special kind of submanifold of a symplectic manifold; see the [definition on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold#Lagrangian_and_other_submanifolds). There was a [question about this on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60201/what-is-a-lagrangian-submanifold-intuitively) not long ago, where you will find some good answers.

Comment: Since again you posted this answer 2 minutes after I posted a comment, let me explain :-). At first I posted it as an answer (with our discussion about comments and answers in mind), but then I realized that the question asked for a lot more than what I wrote, and in fact could be interpreted such that it doesn't actually ask for a raw definition, so I decided to turn it into a comment instead.

Comment: @joriki: Hello again! No need to apologize. Writing that explanation must have been more work for you than writing the comment in the first place. ;)